# Post to entire document like a form using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, hyperlink

i wan't to pass a variable without using get to php, so, i'm using post with jquery, but i can't write the result into the document (refresh all the page)

here is the code:

```
$.post("/"+$(this).attr("href"),{returnto:$(this).attr("rel")},function(a){$(document).html(a);});return false;});
```

Comment: If you are reloading the entire page, why are you using ajax?

Comment: If you want to reload the page, just include a form on the page and submit it from javascript. No need for ajax, no need for jquery even. It's bizarre that people now learn jquery without even learning the basics of how the web works.

Comment: yes, i know that, but i just wanted to put a link to send information with post method, because the link uses always GET method.

the form solution worked, but ok. thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

The document is not the place to write your result as the document is the meta envelope around the html page you see. Rather use the body:

```
$("BODY").html("MY ANSWER IS: "+a);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the page should reload, with new css, etc.